# Fragment Test hangs and then fails

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing

I have the following test for Android:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LogoutFragmentTest {
     @Test
     fun testEventFragment() {
        val scenario = launchFragment<LogoutFragment>(
            initialState = Lifecycle.State.INITIALIZED
        )
        scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
             assertThat(fragment.m_Context).isNotNull()
        }
    }
```

}

I am launching the test from the androidTest folder (with right mouse click)in the project with the option 'Run All tests'. The test launches an emulator, performs some tasks, it announces 'Connected to process .. on device ..' and then starts the task connectedDebugAndroidTests and remains so for a while.

Then it displays a message explaining where the test results are.

```
 Test results saved as file  ...
```

In the test error log I have the following information:

```
 INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: stream=
 Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=
 Time: 0.0

 OK (0 tests)


 INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: -1
```

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this:

I needed to configure the runner in the build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```